# React state checking not working in a async function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have a react template to generate the hand gesture using tensorflow.js. The current code looks like this

```js
const [curstep, setCurstep] = useState(0);
const  detect = async (net) => {
   const hand = await net.estimateHands(video);
   const gesture = await net.estimate(hand[0].landmarks, 4);
   ....
   if (curstep === 0 && gesture === "Number 1")
      setCurstep(1);
   else if (curstep === 1 && gesture === "Number 2")
      setCurstep(2);
   else if (curstep === 2 && gesture === "Number 3")
      setCurstep(3);
   ....
}

const runHandpose = async () => {
   const net = await handpose.load();
   setInterval(() => {detect(net)}, 30);
}

useEffect(() => {runHandpose()}, []);
```

Here my idea is to use `curstep` to track the gesture, and when user sequentially does the gesture "1" and "2" and "3", the app would launch some other UI components. But I had some issues with the state `curstep` is not updating. After some debugging I realize that if I remove the `curstep === 0` condition (and `curstep === 1` etc) it seems that the `curstep` can be updated.

Therefore I am wondering if this is because I am checking the state and updating state in a async function, and what should I do to circumvent this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {runHandpose()}, []);
```

Because of the empty dependency array, this effect is run only once, when the component mounts. Whatever value the const `curstep` had at the time the interval was set up, that's what it will be when the interval goes off.

From the code you provided, it looks like all you need to do to fix this is to use the function version of `setCurstep`, so it can pass you the latest value. Though let me know if something in the code you omitted makes this insufficient.

```
const detect = async (net) => {
   const hand = await net.estimateHands(video);
   const gesture = await net.estimate(hand[0].landmarks, 4);
   setCurstep(prev => {
     ....
     if (prev === 0  && gesture === "Number 1") {
       return 1;
     } else if (prev === 1 && gesture === "Number 2") {
       return 2;
     } else if (prev === 2 && gesture === "Number 3") {
       return 3;
     }
     ....
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for your reply! For the dependency array of `useEffect`, I thought during the `setInterval` it can update the state which is called within the function `detect`? Would you mind explaining more? I am not sure why removing the state checking would make it work. Thanks!

Comment: For functional `setCurstep` I tried that but unfortunately, it does not work in my case. The state remains the same, regardless of whether I put `curstep` in the dependency array or not  .